# Can't see a table in tables_list although I use it in other query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really proficient in SQL and I hope you can help me.

I'm using a sql data-based software and I use this query often: `

```
SELECT vwKontenZuordnung.KontenKategorienKurz
     , vwKontenZuordnung.ktobez
     , KOntoBuchungen.*
FROM   vwKontenZuordnung
JOIN   KOntoBuchungen
  ON KOntoBuchungen.KTyp  = '0'
 AND KOntoBuchungen.KtoNr = vwKontenZuordnung.KtoNr
 AND KOntoBuchungen.Haus  = @VonHaus `
```

For some reason I don't see the tables "vwKontenZuordnung" and "KOntoBuchungen" when I looked for all the tables in the database via:

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

(but there were 389 other tables).

Do you know why is it like this and where can I find all the tables?
Thanks a lot

Comment: it may be a view

Comment: Or it might be a synonym. `SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms; SELECT * FROM sys.views`

Comment: Or look at sys.objects and figure out what type of object it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and it really helped me